# ZK LOCALE DecimalBox conversion

Tags: java, zk

Help.

When I use the decimalBox of ZK and the user's Locale is IT the decimal point gets converted to a comma and this confuses my calculation. How can i stop the conversion please?

I am using ZK 6.5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solution for that.

You can set the Locale for your Webapp to EN like [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Internationalization/Locale#Application-level_Locale).

You can define a "format" attribute for your Decimalbox.

Or you can do it in a simple event handler in ZUL like in [that forum](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/13955/replace-the-decimal-point-in-a-decimalbox/):

> `action="onkeyup:#{self}.value = #{self}.value.replace('.',',');"`

Comment: When using the preferred locale, if the user changes the language to IT for example won't that still change the functionality of the decimal box to work with commas again?

Comment: I am not sure. I think you should test it yourself with your choosen solution. I would do it in defferent browsers.

Comment: The last version of ZK permits you to set the locale for the decimalbox: <decimalbox locale="es"/>

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for a decimalbox which allows to specify the symbols to use to format decimal numbers:

```
package ch.swissquant.zurich.abt.questionnaire.zk;

import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import org.zkoss.json.JSONValue;
import org.zkoss.zul.Decimalbox;

public class SymbolDecimalbox extends Decimalbox {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DecimalFormatSymbols symbols;
    private Locale locale;

    /** Hide the parent method to make sure org.zkoss.zul.impl.NumberInputElement.getRealSymbols() is never called. */
    @Override
    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    /** Hide the parent method to make sure org.zkoss.zul.impl.NumberInputElement.getRealSymbols() is never called. */
    @Override
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setSymbols(DecimalFormatSymbols symbols) {
        this.symbols = symbols;
    }

    public DecimalFormatSymbols getSymbols() {
        return symbols;
    }

    //super//
    @Override
    protected void renderProperties(org.zkoss.zk.ui.sys.ContentRenderer renderer)
    throws java.io.IOException {
        super.renderProperties(renderer);

        // By overriding setLocale(), we make sure org.zkoss.zul.impl.NumberInputElement.getRealSymbols() is never called.
        renderer.render("localizedSymbols", getRealSymbols());
    }

    /** Send the specified symbols to the UI. */
    private String getRealSymbols() {
        if (symbols != null && locale != null) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("GROUPING",
                    String.valueOf(symbols.getGroupingSeparator()));
            map.put("DECIMAL",
                    String.valueOf(symbols.getDecimalSeparator()));
            map.put("PERCENT", String.valueOf(symbols.getPercent()));
            map.put("PER_MILL", String.valueOf(symbols.getPerMill()));
            map.put("MINUS", String.valueOf(symbols.getMinusSign()));

            final String localeName = locale.toString();
            return JSONValue.toJSONString(new Object[] { localeName, map });
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```